# Can I use voice chat in the Xbox 360 minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My family has recently gotten into a Minecraft fix, my wife and I playing with our two children. Because it's the four of us, the Xbox 360 version is perfect.

Recently Grandparents visited and were also enthralled with the game. If they get an Xbox we can sync up and all play together, but is it possible to do voice chat as well? The social aspect is the real selling point. I know Xbox has great voice chat support, but I wasn't sure if it was by game, or a universal feature.

Does Minecraft on Xbox support voice chat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Minecraft for the Xbox 360](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Minecraft-Xbox-360-Edition/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802584111f7) does have online voice chat enabled.

[image]

You can also create a party on Xbox live to voice chat with each other and then join the same hosted session in Minecraft.

Comment: So this would be similar to the PC. Where I use a second program (ventrilo, teamspeak, mumble, etc) first, and use that to talk. Then we could load up Minecraft and play together?

Comment: Similar yes... the Xbox live party is already built into Xbox live.   If you open up your xbox menu, then go to your xbox live friends, you can choose the option to invite to party chat.   Here multiple people will be able to join to chat at once.

Comment: There is also private chat, where your profile and the other profile (the grandparents) can speak exclusively with each other without the need for party privacy settings.

Comment: Note that you need an xboxlive Gold subscription in order to use the party feature.

Comment: the xbox marketplace page (http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Minecraft-Xbox-360-Edition/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802584111f7) says it has voice chat enabled in the game, so you would not need to party up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make parties and talk and play with other people.